# Using a npm module in a Brunch app results in "module not found"

Tags: npm, brunch

I would like to use this node library: https://github.com/sudhirj/simply-deferred

I ran:

```
npm install simply-deferred
```

And added it to package.json under dependencies.

```
"simply-deferred": "*"
```

It installed successfully:

```
> require ("simply-deferred")
{ Deferred: [Function],
  when: [Function],
  installInto: [Function] }
```

But it is not added to vendor.js, and when I run require("simply-defered"), it says module not found (even when I manually added the js file to /vendors).

I am a npm/node beginner.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot require NPM modules in brunch app. From the site:

> Brunch is a HTML5 application assembler

npm is node.js package manager. Brunch is HTML5 app builder. Different stuff.