# Brunch - Requiring modules outside of app directory

Tags: javascript, brunch

There have been answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17418027/using-a-npm-module-in-a-brunch-app) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102962/brunch-require-with-node-js-modules), but they're about using NPM modules whilst my problem involves isomorphic internal code, where I want to share routes between brunch/backbone and node/express. But, if this is a dupe, then apologies in advance!

The following code is highly simplified/pseudo, btw.

Currently, this works:

---

#### web/client/app/lib/router.coffee

```
Routes = require 'lib/routesList'
module.exports = class Router extends Backbone.Router
  routes: Routes.get()
```

#### web/client/app/lib/routesList.coffee

```
module.exports = do () ->
  get: () ->
    return {'': 'dashboard', 'settings': 'settings'}
```

---

However, this doesn't:

---

#### web/client/app/lib/router.coffee

```
Routes = require '../../shared/routes/routesList'
module.exports = class Router extends Backbone.Router
  routes: Routes.get()
```

#### web/shared/routes/routesList.coffee

```
module.exports = do () ->
  get: () ->
    return {'': 'dashboard', 'settings': 'settings'}
```

---

I'm not trying to get node modules to work with Brunch- I know that's not supported- but is it at all possible to just concatenate these common js modules together into app.js when they don't all reside within the app directory?

Many thanks!

### Update:

I ended up creating a symbolic link between `web/client/app/shared` -> `web/shared` and it now works, but I don't know if there's a cleaner way...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `../../shared` to the watched paths in your brunch config

```
paths:
  watched: ['app', 'vendor', '../../shared']
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for my slow response. I added `../shared` to my paths and it now picks up the files and appends them to my app.js, but I still can't get require() to pick up the module, even using every combination of `shared/router`, `../shared/router`, `../../shared/router`, `router`, `../router` etc etc. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: It also seems that `require.register("../shared/routes/routes", callback)` doesn't actually work- if I manually edit app.js to remove the `../`, then all combinations of `shared/routes/routes`, `../shared/routes/routes`, etc works!