# Is it bad practice to build the server API as part of a brunch application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-services, express, brunch

I am using [brunch](http://brunch.io) to build a single-page web application. The application talks to an backend CRUD API that I would like to write using node.js/express. The natural thing to me seems to be to build out the server in a subdirectory of my application, parallel to `app`. This has the advantage of having all of the code under one roof as well has allowing me to start everything up via `brunch watch --server`.

I started doing this and then I became worried. If I have server-side dependencies that I install via `npm install --save-dev some-server-dependency`, do these dependencies get embedded into the javascript of my single-page application? This seems like it would unnecessarily increase the size of my app. If this doesn't happen, how does brunch know what dependencies to include in `vendor.js`?

This leads to more general questions: Is it bad practice to develop the API in the same project as the client code? If so, are there any `brunch` equivalents for building the server-side API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not bad practice, and there are Brunch skeleton examples that do the same thing. You've already mentioned that you're putting your server-side code in a separate directory from `app`, so as long as that other directory is not in the `paths.watched` of your brunch config, then your back-end code will not be included in your concatenated front-end code. [You can even have shared code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301406/brunch-requiring-modules-outside-of-app-directory) between your client and server apps, which is great for things like input validation.

There may be situations where you'd eventually want to break out your server side code into something separate, but the approach you'd described should make that very easy to accomplish if/when that time comes.

To answer that last question regarding brunch equivalents for node applications, there are several tools that will automatically restart a node process whenever you edit its code such as [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon), [supervisor](https://github.com/isaacs/node-supervisor), and [node-dev](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev). Since Brunch won't handle this part for you (a future version may add this ability), anytime you are actively hacking on server side code you may want to run `brunch watch` and the server separately with one of these tools.

Comment: When I use `npm` sometimes I want a client-side external dependency and I want it to be included in `vendor.js` and sometimes I want a server-side  dependency and I don't want it in `vendor.js`. How do I control which kind of dependency it is? For example, in my seed `bower_component/angular/angular.js` is included in `files.javascripts.joinTo`, but `node_modules/.../express.js` is not. What determines whether it is joined in `vendor.js`? Preferably this is automated for me somehow. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Bower components are assumed to be meant for client-side and get bundled. npm/node_modules do not get bundled into your client-side code at all by Brunch unless you very explicitly ask it to by specifying the paths/files in your `paths.watched` and `joinTo` config. The ability to include npm dependencies in your client-side code in a more automated way will be coming in a future version of Brunch: https://github.com/brunch/brunch/issues/882